# Multiply a Scalar by an Exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I have the formula $A * B^2$ and I want to scale B by 2, what would I need to do to A to balance the formula.  Would this be valid?

$A * B^2 = (\frac{A}{2}) * (2*B)^2$

Comment: That is valid, but it is not scaling $B$ by 2.  To scale $B$ by 2, you will want $(2B)^2$ in there.  Then what o you need to do to $A$?

Comment: Right, because exponents are evaluated first.  So then would the following be valid?

$A * B^2 = (\frac{A}{2}) * (2*B)^2$

Comment: By the way, if the answer you got satisfies you, don't forget to accept it!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(2*B)^2=2^2*B^2=4*B^2$. So what do you have to do to $A$ in order to balance the formula?

Comment: $A * B^2 = (\frac{A}{2^2}) * (2*B)^2$ ?

Comment: yes,  exactly! :)

Comment: Fantastic!  Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome!